# What is the use of Cacheable Annotation

Tags: spring, ehcache

Can somebody please explain what is the difference between

`com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.Cacheable`
and
`org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable`

if I replace first one with second one what will be the effect?

I have used `@Cacheable` in a web service coded using spring

```java
@Cacheable(value = "policyCache")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseVO> listById(@PathVariable(value = "id") )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring 3 introduces a new abstraction layer for caching services. The idea is to provide a set of common features, mainly annotations, to activate and manage the caches.
Since it is only an abstract layer, Spring 3 caching still need a concrete implementation to work. The entry point for cache implementation is the `CacheManager` interface. By default 2 concrete implementation of `CacheManager` are provided:
`EhCacheCacheManager`: default implementation for `EhCache`
`ConcurrentMapCacheManager`: default implementation using Java `ConcurrentHashMap` as cache store.

With the use of `com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.Cacheable`, you rely immediately on the `ehCache` implementation.

If you use the Spring annotations, you don't have to do any code adaptations if you want to change your cache implementation later on, so I would advise to use the latter.